# WYSIWYG – Getting the "link" button from HTML mode in Visual mode

Tags: admin, tinymce, wysiwyg, links, buttons

Pretty much as the title says, I want to use the "link" button from the HTML mode in the Visual Mode in the WYSIWYG editor (the link/unlink in visual is to "advanced" for my liking). Is this possible without too much of a hassle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but no. :) You can't simply use the html-button in the wysiwyg-editor. Both are different programms and have nothing in common except for their location. You'd have to unregister the current buttons, write code for a new one (that fits your likings) and then add this one. You'll find hundreds of tutorials for adding buttons to tinyMCE both on google, as here in WPSE.

Comment: Right, thank you for letting me know. I'm curious though, have you seen any thread/tutorial about adding a link button like the one I'm looking for? I've only seen a few that registers an entirely new functionality..

Comment: You could take a look at the Button in WP-Core and then reduce it to your needs. You'll need those tutorials anyway as they will help you to register and de-register the buttons.